# Is the automatic deletion of outdated branches possible in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

At some point, you will have a lot of old / outdated branches.

Is it possible in Gitlab to delete all outdated branches(e.g: last activity older than 3 months) automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a shell script where you mention old branches to be deleted. You can fetch those old branches using the *GitLab API*. Please check the [official API-documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html#delete-repository-branch).

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/branches/"
```

Answer (score 1):

As of now, GitLab itself does not have such feature. `@Anirbas Das`'s idea of a cronjob could be implemented.

A feature request for what you what does exist: *[Gitlab: Auto delete branches based on user criteria](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/34031)*.